# How to get good spacing in math mode with object dot notation

Tags: math-mode, spacing

When formatting object dot notation ("x.next") in math mode I want to combine a math-mode variable (x) with a field name (next), separated by a period.  For this I've been using code `$x.\textit{next}`.  LaTeX, however, makes the spacing look poor depending on the variable name preceding the field.  With a variable named "f" it looks quite bad [image: f.next]. Adding negative space helps, but the amount of negative space needed to fix it seems to depend on the variable itself.  For example, one `\!` is not quite sufficient for "f" [image], but two looks ok [image], whereas if the variable name is "e" one is a little tight but maybe ok [image], and two is quite bad [image].

Putting both the variable and the field name in the `\textit` works, but the font for the variable name is then different from normal made mode, so that's not a solution.  Is there any way to fix the spacing between the variable and the period, without needing to make separate macros for each different variable name?

Comment: Wecome to TeX.SX! What prevents you from using `\textit{f.next}`? I would probably not typeset such things in italics, but this might be a matter of taste.

Comment: Thanks.  Single-letter variables I've typeset in regular math mode throughout, and the font is slightly different between math-mode and `\textit`, so mixing `$f$` and `\textit{f.next}` makes the "f"s look like subtly different symbols.  I'd really rather not have to change every single variable use to `\textit` just to accommodate the few places where object notation is used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd use a command for this and compensate using the italic correction of the math italic symbol.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\sv}[2]{% subscripted variable
  #1%
  \kern-\fontcharic\textfont1`#1 %
  \mathit{.#2}%
}

\begin{document}

$\sv{f}{next}+\sv{e}{next}+\sv{y}{next}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work nicely!

Comment: @UsingLatexForCode Don't use it for other than Latin letters.

Comment: Thanks, yes, I noticed that too. :)  Still amply sufficient in my case.